# Can I use an alias instead of my full name when licensing my code?

Tags: licensing

On many (if not all) open source licenses there is a copyright notice which shows who the copyright holder is, e.g:

```
Copyright (c) [year] [fullname]
```

For legal reasons, do I actually have to include my *Full Name* in the `[fullname]` field or can I substitute my online alias?